# Why does returning inside the ternary operator throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript

What is the different? And why it get the error in the function a()?

```
function a(){
    1 == 1 ? return true: "";  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
}

function b(){
    1 == 1 ? console.log(true):"";  // correct
}

function c(){
    if (1==1) return true;  // correct
}
```

Comment: Homework ? Also would be nice if you give the results of each rather than us running it for yah! you get an error in a because of 'return true :' return means return {x}, the operand after doesnt count.

Comment: The first two functions are using _ternaries_.  A _ternary_ is a special / briefer form of an `if ... else` statement, and cannot contain a `return`.  Instead, function a should read `return (1 == 1) ? true : false` - which of course can be shortened to `return (1 == 1)`.  Function b should read `if (1 == 1) { console.log(true);}`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` is a statement: it can only exist *standalone*, like an `if` statement, and cannot be parsed as a value. The conditional operator requires values (expressions) only. Its syntax is:

```
cond ? expr1 : expr2
```

where `cond`, `expr1`, and `expr2` are all *expressions*. The whole conditional operator will evaluate to `expr1` if `cond` is truthy, and `expr2` otherwise.

Similarly, this is invalid:

```
1 === 1
  ? if (foo) {
    // do something
  }
  : ''
```

What you put after the `?` and the `:` of the conditional operator *must always evaluate to a value* - that is, it must be an *expression* only. `return`, being only a statement, cannot evaluate to a value (just like an `if` statement cannot evaluate to a value).

`console.log`, on the other hand, *is* an expression, which evaluates to `undefined`.

If you only want to return `true` if the conditional is fulfilled in `a`, then you'll have to use a full-fledged `if`:

```
function a() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  // other statements here
}
```

If you wanted to return `true` if the conditional is fulfilled, and return the empty string otherwise, then you can put the `return` on the left and use the conditional operator:

```
function a() {
  return 1 == 1
    ? true
    : '';
}
```

Use the conditional operator when you need to create an *expression* conditionally. If you need to do anything other than create a conditional expression (for example, if you want to `return` a particular value if a condition is fulfilled, and continue the rest of the function otherwise), you should use `if` instead.

Comment: Beautiful answer, based on this i think the question title should be phrased more appropriately too.

Comment: May be worth mentioning the conflation of ternary with if statements... OP appears to be attempting to use a ternary without understanding that's what it is...

Comment: @cale_b i change the title to kinda suite.. Maybe could be something better ?